# How to interpolate a slice in 2d non regular griddata?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate a slice (blue line) in 2d griddata (non-regular).

Minimal Example. I want to interpolate the data of psi in that blue line -

[image: Minimal Example. I want to interpolate the data of psi in that blue line]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
y = np.linspace(400,500,100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)


Vec = np.array([X, Y])

psi = 90 - np.rad2deg(np.arccos(Vec[0,:,:] / np.linalg.norm(Vec, axis=0)))

R = np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2)

# points for interpolation
x_points = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max())
y_points = [480] * len(x_points)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(X, R, psi, level=20)
ax.plot(x_points, y_points)
```

My Problem with the scipy function I found, was that they can either not read non-regular meshgrid data or just interpolate on a new grid -> expensive.

Is there a function which just interpolates a few points (x_points and y_points) in that minimal example?

Comment: Perharps consider using ordinary kriging . I believe the package is `gstats`

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Your contour axes are X and radius, but then you plot a line with x and "y reinterpreted as a radius". Surely this isn't what you actually want?

Comment: The curve of interpolation is not irregular; it's not even non-linear. It's just y=480, for which you already have an entry in your `y` array. At most this is a call to `searchsorted` to find the index into `psi` for which y=480, but in reality not even that - your `psi` function is known, so just... call it with a constant `y`.

Comment: In your last call to `linspace` you haven't specified your resolution, so it defaults to `50`. Are you sure that that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an interpolation question. Your function is known, so just call it with the fixed y-value you showed:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-50,50, num=50)
y = 480
r = np.sqrt(y**2 + x**2)
psi = 90 - np.rad2deg(np.arccos(x / r))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, psi)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('psi')
ax.set_title(f'y={y}')
plt.show()
```

Even if you don't know the function, this is *still* not an interpolation question, because the coordinate space is both regular and linear:

```py
x = np.linspace(-50,50,101)
y = np.linspace(400,500,101)
XY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
vec = np.stack(XY)
R = np.linalg.norm(vec, axis=0)
psi = 90 - np.rad2deg(np.arccos(vec[0, ...] / R))

# Boundary of function knowledge

yidx = y.searchsorted(v=480)
psi_interest = psi[yidx, :]
```